# Remove Top View From Hierarchy When Saving Screenshot

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, core-graphics, calayer

I am using a method to take a UIImage screenshot **programatically** which works very nicely. What I want to do now is remove the top most UIView from being included in the screenshot **BUT** not remove it from the actual view on screen so simply setting `topView.hidden = YES` won't do. I am using this method to save the screenshot:

```
- (UIImage*)screenshot
{
CGSize imageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
else
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Iterate over every window from back to front
for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows])
{
    if (![window respondsToSelector:@selector(screen)] || [window screen] == [UIScreen mainScreen])
    {
        // -renderInContext: renders in the coordinate space of the layer,
        // so we must first apply the layer's geometry to the graphics context
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        // Center the context around the window's anchor point
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [window center].x, [window center].y);
        // Apply the window's transform about the anchor point
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, [window transform]);
        // Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
                              -[window bounds].size.width * [[window layer] anchorPoint].x,
                              -[window bounds].size.height * [[window layer] anchorPoint].y);

        // Render the layer hierarchy to the current context
        [[window layer] renderInContext:context];

        // Restore the context
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }
}

// Retrieve the screenshot image
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return image;
}
```

My first thought was to remove the sublayer from the superlayer doing this:

```
NSArray *sublayers = [[window layer] sublayers];
[[window layer] replaceSublayer:[sublayers objectAtIndex:[sublayers count] - 1] with:nil];
```

but I found that the `sublayers` array is only 1 object. How could I remove the top view from the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

For example you have View1 on your view hierarchy and you don't want to take screenshot of View1 then you can do View1.hiden= TRUE; before screenshot and you can do View1.hiden= FALSE; after screenshot.

May be this will help you.

Comment: Nah, that was the first thing I tried. Too much of a delay. Looks cheesy.